# Категоризация столбца по интервалам значений

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

Имеется DF , состоящий из 1 столбца с данными, необходимо создать второй столбец, где значение ставится в зависимости от значения соответствующего значения в 1 столбце.
Итак, допустим есть один столбец А, если А =

```
[0,10] , то столбец B = Bb
[11,20] = Cc
[21,30] = Dd
```

Должны получить что-то такое

```
A   B
5   Bb
12  Cc
15  Cc
21  Dd
20  Cc
26  Dd
20  Cc
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Воспользуйтесь функцией [pd.cut()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.4/generated/pandas.cut.html):

исходный DF:

```
In [94]: df
Out[94]:
    A
0   5
1  12
2  15
3  21
4  20
5  26
6  20
```

решение:

```
In [95]: bins = [-10**8,11,21,10**8]

In [96]: labels = ['Bb','Cc','Dd']

In [97]: df['B'] = pd.cut(df['A'], bins=bins, labels=labels, right=False)
```

результат:

```
In [98]: df
Out[98]:
    A   B
0   5  Bb
1  12  Cc
2  15  Cc
3  21  Dd
4  20  Cc
5  26  Dd
6  20  Cc
```

---

границы интервалов:

```
In [99]: pd.cut(df['A'], bins=bins)  # per default: `right=True`
Out[99]:
0    (-100000000, 11]
1            (11, 21]
2            (11, 21]
3            (11, 21]
4            (11, 21]
5     (21, 100000000]
6            (11, 21]
Name: A, dtype: category
Categories (3, interval[int64]): [(-100000000, 11] < (11, 21] < (21, 100000000]]


In [100]: pd.cut(df['A'], bins=bins, right=False)
Out[100]:
0    [-100000000, 11)
1            [11, 21)
2            [11, 21)
3     [21, 100000000)
4            [11, 21)
5     [21, 100000000)
6            [11, 21)
Name: A, dtype: category
Categories (3, interval[int64]): [[-100000000, 11) < [11, 21) < [21, 100000000)]
```

Comment: Отлично, работает, но видимо ограничение на bins стоит, что только целые числа, а что делать если нужно с более мелкими значениями работать? И `3  21  Cc` должно получиться `Dd`

Comment: @Max, как обычно - приведите воспроизводимый пример ;-) @Max `3  21  Cc` вы хотите чтобы интервалы включали правые границы?

Comment: Да, верно. Я поэтому и указал [0,10], ну типо как в математике границы)

Comment: Хорошо, но почему `3 21 Cc` должно же быть `Dd`

Comment: И опять вопрос , почему 21 - это Сс, я хочу чтобы было Dd, как я писал в условии), если мы добавляем границы, то может есть смысл указать
`bins = np.array([-10**8,10,20,10**8]) + 1e-7`  ?

Comment: Прошу прощения, по умолчанию, включены как раз правые границы, а левые открытые... Смотрите обновленный ответ

Comment: Благодарю, вопрос закрыт)